# Incorrectly Changing WordPress URLs on Same Server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, directory

So we have a dedicated server and we installed a single instance of Wordpress on this URL (using URL as example): AnytownBoatTours.com.  Started themes and plugins etc... and the owner said the URL needs to be the other way around:  BoatToursAnytown.com.

So, we pointed the new domain to existing instance of WordPress (since they are on the same dedicated server), and then I followed wordpress instructions by going into Settings -> General and changed both the Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to BoatToursAnytown.com  (with no "/" at ending on either).

So, everything appears to be fine.  The Wordpress site seems to have accepted the URL change and I've logged in and made changes to the home page and theme.  Then I came across a weird error with sub pages I'd created before the switch.  The error occurs in all pages except the home page.  When  I click on any of the pages except home and edit them, when I hit update or preview buttons, the preview goes to a 404 message.  I thought that is weird so I started looking around.

I discovered that the content directory is still pointing back to the old URL.  The Wp-config Location is:  D:\Websites\AnytownBoatTours.com/wp-config.php and the Content Directory is: D:\Websites\AnytownBoatTours.com/wp-content

So obviously the change in General Settings didn't work.  I was hoping someone could help me figure how to go from here.

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes pages themselves contain links that need to be updated.  Check out [the codex page on moving](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change), specifically the Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script.

Answer (score 0):

Update your permalinks even if it's not changing them, you just need to click the save. Settings > Permalinks and press Save Changes. This will more then likely fix the issue as I had to do it when I recently migrated a clients site.